# Spring Boot Admin registering error

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I get this on server log when trying to register an app:

```
Failed to read HTTP message:  org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of de.codecentric.boot.admin.model.Application: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of de.codecentric.boot.admin.model.Application: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@765cecc4; line: 1, column: 2]
```

What may be the problem here?

I am using Spring Boot Admin v1.5.7

Comment: I guess you're not using jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to extend `AbstractHttpMessageConverter`:

```java
public class MappingJackson2String2HttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {
    //...
    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return supportedClasses.contains(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canWrite(MediaType mediaType) {
        return mediaType == null || mediaType.toString().contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        Charset charset = getContentTypeCharset(inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        return StreamUtils.copyToString(inputMessage.getBody(), charset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object linkedHashMap, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getHeaders().setAcceptCharset(getAcceptedCharsets());
        Charset charset = getContentTypeCharset(outputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType());
        String result = linkedHashMap instanceof String ? (String) linkedHashMap : objectMapper.writeValueAsString(linkedHashMap);
        StreamUtils.copy(result, charset, outputMessage.getBody());
    }
    //...
}
```

and add it as a message converter at app configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class BackendConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2String2HttpMessageConverter());
        //...
    }
}
```

because I was receiving an encrypted payload as `plain/text` content type.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with you...
i figured out the reason.
This is my solution:

```
        @Configuration
    public class JacksonConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
            objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule",
                    Version.unknownVersion());
            simpleModule.addSerializer(JsonResult.class, new CustomJsonResultSerializer());
            simpleModule.addDeserializer(Application.class, new ApplicationDeserializer());
            objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
            objectMapper.setInjectableValues(new IgnoreNullFieldInjectableValues());
            return objectMapper;
        }
}
```

`addDeserializer(Application.class, new ApplicationDeserializer());`

de.codecentric.boot.admin.jackson.ApplicationDeserializer
de.codecentric.boot.admin.model.Application

you must use `ApplicationDeserializer` to deserialize the model `Application`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I was getting error:

> :29:47.072 [http-nio-8088-exec-5] WARN 
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver
>   - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON document: Can not construct instance of
>   de.codecentric.boot.admin.model.Application: no suitable constructor
>   found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default
>   constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type
>   information?)  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@30d871a4; line:
>   1, column: 2]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of de.codecentric.boot.admin.model.Application: no suitable
>   constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing
>   default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type
>   information?)  at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@30d871a4; line:
>   1, column: 2]

```
@Configuration
    public class JacksonConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", Version.unknownVersion());
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(Application.class, new ApplicationDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```